# R - Mapa de cidades brasileiras

Tags: r, mapas

Bom dia,

Estou tentando criar um mapa brasileiro que apresente a quantidade de cooperativas presente em cada cidade.

Tenho uma tabela com o código do IBGE dos municípios e a quantidade de coop.

Peguei o shapefile no site do IBGE:

https://downloads.ibge.gov.br/downloads_geociencias.htm

e tentei seguir esse exemplo:

https://dataficacao.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/criando-mapa-brasil-r/

Entretanto, quando aplicado aos municípios, o R fica processando por uns minutos e de repente trava. O que pode ser?

Mais uma pergunta, gostaria de deixar a divisão por Estados e Regiões aparecendo. É possível?

Segue abaixo linhas de código:

```
shpmun <- readOGR("G:/Lupa Econômica/Ricardo/Qtd de 
Coop/dados/MAPA/BRMUE250GC_SIR.shp", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, encoding="UTF-8")

load('G:/Lupa Econômica/Ricardo/Qtd de 
Coop/dados/Rais_Coop_Estb_2016.RData') 

Rais_Coop_Estb_2016$Cont <- as.numeric(c(1))

Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun <- Rais_Coop_Estb_2016 %>% group_by(Município) 
%>% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Cont))
Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun <- Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun %>% 
group_by(Município) %>%  summarise(Score= max(cumsum))
Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun <- as.data.frame(Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun)

brasileiropgmun <- merge(shpmun,Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun, by.x = 
"CD_GEOCMU", by.y = "Município")

proj4string(brasileiropgmun) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs") 
#adicionando coordenadas geográficas

Encoding(brasileiropgmun$NM_MUNICIP) <- "UTF-8"

brasileiropgmun$Score[is.na(brasileiropgmun$Score)] <- 0 

display.brewer.all()

pal <- colorBin("YlGn",domain = NULL,n=20) #cores do mapa

state_popupmun <- paste0("<strong>Município: </strong>", 
                  brasileiropgmun$NM_MUNICIP, 
                  "<br><strong>Pontos: </strong>", 
                  brasileiropgmun$Score)
leaflet(data = brasileiropgmun) %>%
addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(brasileiropgmun$Score), 
          fillOpacity = 0.8, 
          color = "#BDBDC3", 
          weight = 1, 
          popup = state_popupmun) %>%
addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = ~brasileiropgmun$Score,
        title = "Pontos Conquistados",
        opacity = 1)
```

** A legenda também não está aparecendo.

Comment: Veja se este link ajuda: <https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/315747/como-inserir-uma-legenda-em-um-mapa-no-r-com-o-package-rcolorbrewer>

Comment: Muito Obrigado, ajudou em partes ! Na minha base de coop tenho: cada linha uma coop e cada coop está ligada a um município. Como faria para agrupar elas e representar no mapa? Ex: quanto mais a cor for escura, maior o número de coop na região?

Comment: Tentei usar Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun <- Rais_Coop_Estb_2016 %>% group_by(Município) %>% mutate(cumsum = cumsum(Cont))
Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun <- Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun %>% group_by(Município) %>%  summarise(Score= max(cumsum))
Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun <- as.data.frame(Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun) , mas como acrescentaria isso no exemplo ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As últimas versões do ggplot2 possuem geometria específica para mapas. A grande vantagem é não precisar unir o data.frame com os dados com o objeto espacial (mas para isso o objeto espacial precisa ser convertido para um formato que o ggplot entende com `fortify`). O importante é apenas que ambos possuam uma coluna de identificação (o código de municípios do IBGE, no caso) com o mesmo nome.

Para plotar as margens dos Estados, regiões, etc, o melhor é usar um objeto distinto para cada um. Podem ser shapefiles diferentes ou um novo objeto espacial gerado por união de atributos usando o próprio R (com o pacote rgeos, por exemplo).

Estou usando shapefiles que já possuo, baseados na [versão mais atual do FTP do IBGE](ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2017/Brasil/BR/).

```
library(ggplot2)

shpMun <- rgdal::readOGR('./shapefiles', 'municipios')
mapaMun <- fortify(shpMun, region = 'GEOCODE')

shpUFs <- rgdal::readOGR('./shapefiles', 'ufs')

# Simulando as informações de cooperativas
dadosCoop <- data.frame(
  GEOCODE = shpMun@data$GEOCODE,
  cooperativas = sample(1:20, length(shpMun@data$GEOCODE), replace = TRUE) )
#

ggplot(dadosCoop) +
  geom_map(
    map = mapaMun,
    color = 'gray60', size = .1,
    aes(map_id = GEOCODE, fill = cooperativas)
  ) +
  expand_limits(
    x = mapaMun$long,
    y = mapaMun$lat
  ) +
  scale_fill_gradient(
    low = 'lightyellow',
    high = 'darkred'
  ) +
  geom_path(
    data = shpUFs,
    size = .2,
    aes(long, lat, group = group)
  ) +
  coord_map() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.2,0.3))

ggsave('mapa.png', width = 8, height = 8, dpi = 100)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado !

Comment: Fiz as adaptações para minha situação, e está retornando este erro: Error in seq_len(nrow(data) - 1) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer , o que pode ser ?

Comment: Mais uma coisa, poderia explicar melhor o fortfy() ?

Comment: `fortify` converte um objeto para um data.frame com estrutura reconhecível pelo ggplot2; o método depende da classe do objeto. Embora o ggplot possa plotar objetos espaciais sem essa conversão (caso da borda dos Estados), ela é necessária para o geom_map para que seja feita a ligação ("inner join") com o data.frame com os dados. A alternativa é manter o shape dos municípios como objeto do tipo polígono espacial, unir os dados com `merge` e plotar no ggplot com a opção `geom_polygon`. Mas isso é bem menos eficiente por conta do merge.

Comment: Quanto ao erro, difícil dizer sem ver os seus dados. Provavelmente tenha linhas repetidas (mais de uma linha com mesmo id). Evite usar os nomes dos municípios: tem municípios com mesmo nome em Estados diferentes e às vezes tem variação na grafia entre diferentes bases de dados. Prefira sempre o código do IBGE; se está tirando os dados da base RAIS, ele está lá.

Comment: Como eu poderia mostrar?

Comment: Você pode compartilhar seu conjunto completo de dados? Se sim, exporte as colunas relevantes para um arquivo externo, coloque em um serviço de compartilhamento (p.e. Dropbox) e inclua o link na pergunta. Você também pode rodar `dput(rbind(head(Rais_Coop_Estb_2016),tail(Rais_Coop_Estb_2016)))` e colar a saída na pergunta; isso dará uma ideia da estrutura dos seus dados, mas provavelmente não irá incluir as linhas que estão dando problema. Sugiro abrir uma nova questão específica para isso ("Agregando dados por município", ou algo assim), de modo que todos possam ajudar a achar uma solução.

Comment: Tem como colocar o nome de cada Estado no mapa?

Comment: Tem, ou como legenda ou com os nomes sobre o mapa. Mas é melhor abrir uma pergunta só para isso.

Answer (score 3):

O novo pacote [`geobr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geobr/index.html) facilita bastante a tarefa.

```
# instalando pacote
  install.packages("geobr")
  library(geobr)

# carregando shape files de todos municipios do Brasil
  mun <- read_municipality(code_muni="all", year=2016)


# gerando mapa
  library(dplyr)
  library(sf)
  library(ggplot2)

  mun <- left_joint(mun, Rais_Coop_Estb_2016mapamun, by= c("code_muni" = "Município"))

  ggplot() + geom_sf(data=mun, aes(fill= Score))
```